# Passing in "const string &test" is bugging me

Tags: constants

Hello wonderful folks,

I'm scratching my head regarding this issue. 'Const' means the contents are not changed, but '&' means the contents can be modified. So how do they both bond together?

Answer (score 0):

& means that the contents are passed by reference, not necessarily that they are modified. Rather, it means that the object is not copied, meaning that its copy constructor isn't invoked to pass it. The confusion may arise because *one* (common) use of a reference is to allow the callee to modify the referenced object.

A const reference, as shown here, is a pretty natural way to express that a reference to an object will be passed without copying the object, *and* that the callee will not modify the object. It's a simple and somewhat effective optimization when the object is expensive to copy, the callee doesn't need to modify it, and there are no relevant lifetime concerns that would require a copy to be taken.